# cassandra schema design to avoid IN

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am new to Cassandra. I have the following fields:

```
A text,
B bigint, ( value is among [0,1,2,3] )
C time
```

I　need　ｔｏ　ｄｏ　ｃｏｕｎｔｉｎｇ．My design is: A partition key, B and C clustering keys.
But my queries look like:

```
Select count(*) from mykeyspace.mytable where A='a' and B in (1,2,3) and C > 0 and C< 100;
Select count(*) from mykeyspace.mytable where A='a' and B in (0, 1,2,3) and C > 0 and C< 100;
```

**There are two issues: the second query is 'weird', because I need to restrict B and the C. And it is recommended to avoid in in the query. How to re-design the schema and do the queries?** http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause

Thanks

**UPDATE**

0 and 100 in the above queries are hardcodes.

Comment: If the `C` parameters are always `0` and `100`, why are you inserting that data in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since A is your partition key, the IN part of your query on B all happens within a single partition, so I think its fine to do this.

Cassandra will be able to do this COUNT within a single partition.

Although it may be a concern that you have enough records in a single partition to require doing a count with multiple WHERE causes. This might mean that your partitions are too big.

Comment: DO you mean that it is OK to use IN here?

Comment: Basically yeh. Since you provide the partition key `where A='a' `, Cassandra will only need to retrieve one partition. Then the IN part is wholly contains within in single partition, so its pretty fast.

The use of IN is discouraged when it spans multiple partitions because the coordinator has too do a lot of work to retrieve all the relevant partitions.

Answer (score 0):

How frequently do you need to get that data? If you perform reads more often than writes, it would be worth counting during writes instead of counting during reads and store and retrieve that number only instead, so you could get your number in a lightweight manner instead of telling C* to read a bunch of record every time. You'd stress a lot less your cluster.

To do that you should create a table that tell you exactly what you want, instantly. The design however depends on how you are performing your queries (eg in that `C > 0 AND C < 100` are `0` and `100` hard coded or can change often?), so we would need more information to give you some other advice.